# Sorting a hash in Ruby by its value first then its key

Tags: ruby

I am trying to sort a document based on the number of times the word appears then alphabetically by the words so when it is outputted it will look something like this.

```
Unsorted:
'the', '6'
'we', '7'
'those', '5'
'have', '3'

Sorted:
'we', '7'
'the', '6'
'those', '5'
'have', '3'
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding something to the unsorted list that help make it clear if sorting on the word alphabetically is working.  I added `and => 6`, meaning we should see `and, 6` before `the, 6`.

Comment: I have updated my answer to solve your problem more cleanly :). Check it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

Assuming:

```
a = { 
  'the' => '6', 
  'we' => '7', 
  'those' => '5', 
  'have' => '3', 
  'hav' => '3', 
  'haven' => '3'
}
```

then after doing this:

```
b = a.sort_by { |x, y| [ -Integer(y), x ] }
```

`b` will look like this:

```
[
  ["we", "7"], 
  ["the", "6"], 
  ["those", "5"], 
  ["hav", "3"], 
  ["have", "3"], 
  ["haven", "3"]
]
```

Edited to sort by reverse frequencies.

Comment: this post is quite old. but thought id try. what is the -Integer(y) part doing if it's not changing y to an integer?

Comment: @ZachSmith it is making the number negative, in effect reversing the sort order to largest to smallest from smallest to largest.

Answer (score 3):

```
words = {'the' => 6,'we' => 7,'those' => 5,'have' => 3}
sorted_words = words.sort { |a,b| b.last <=> a.last }
sorted_words.each { |k,v| puts "#{k} #{v}"}
```

produces:

```
we 7
the 6
those 5
have 3
```

You probably want the values to be integers rather than strings for comparison purposes.

**EDIT**

Oops, overlooked the requirement that it needs to be sorted by the key too. So:

```
words = {'the' => 6,'we' => 7,'those' => 5,'have' => 3,'zoo' => 3,'foo' => 3}
sorted_words = words.sort do |a,b|
  a.last == b.last ? a.first <=> b.first : b.last <=> a.last
end
sorted_words.each { |k,v| puts "#{k} #{v}"}
```

produces:

```
we 7
the 6
those 5
foo 3
have 3
zoo 3
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `sort` method on a hash, you receive two element arrays in your comparison block, with which you can do comparisons in one pass.

```
hsh = { 'the' => '6', 'we' => '6', 'those' => '5', 'have' => '3'}
ary = hsh.sort do |a,b|
  # a and b are two element arrays in the format [key,value]
  value_comparison = a.last <=> b.last
  if value_comparison.zero?
    # compare keys if values are equal
    a.first <=> b.first
  else
    value_comparison
  end
end
# => [['have',3],['those',5],['the',6],['we',6]]
```

Note that the result is an array of arrays because hashes do not have intrinsic order in ruby

Comment: Thanks.  I was looking at http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000743 for `Hash#sort` docs, and they are quite inadequate.  Knew there should be a better way.

Comment: Actually, you should check out the [sort method in the Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001480). That is where Hash gets its sorting functionality.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that bit out.  What I didn't immediately realize was that it would return an array of arrays.  I guess `Hash#each` effectively returns a pair, so I should have figured on something like that.

Comment: Rather than `value_comparison...`, I just used `b.last <=> a.last || a.first <=> b.first`.  Not sure which, if either, is better.

Comment: Be careful, I considered that but in Ruby, `0` evaluates to `true`. Since `<=>` returns `0` for equality, that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
words = {'the' => 6,'we' => 7,'those' => 5,'have' => 3}

words.sort { |(x_k, x_v), (y_k, y_v)| [y_v, y_k] <=> [x_v, x_k]}
#=> [["we", 7], ["the", 6], ["those", 5], ["have", 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
histogram = { 'the' => 6, 'we' => 7, 'those' => 5, 'have' => 3, 'and' => 6 }

Hash[histogram.sort_by {|word, freq| [-freq, word] }]
# {
#   'we'    => 7,
#   'and'   => 6,
#   'the'   => 6,
#   'those' => 5,
#   'have'  => 3
# }
```

Note: this assumes that you use numbers to store the numbers. In your data model, you appear to use strings to store the numbers. I have no idea why you would want to do this, but if you *do* want to do this, you would obviously have to convert them to numbers before sorting and then back to strings.

Also, this assumes Ruby 1.9. In Ruby 1.8, hashes aren't ordered, so you cannot convert the sorted result back to a hash since that would lose the ordering information, you would have to keep it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
word_counts = {
        'the' => 6,
        'we' => 7,
        'those' => 5,
        'have' => 3,
        'and' => 6
};

word_counts_sorted = word_counts.sort do
        |a,b|
        # sort on last field descending, then first field ascending if necessary
        b.last <=> a.last || a.first <=> b.first
end

puts "Unsorted\n"
word_counts.each do
        |word,count|
        puts word + " " + count.to_s
end

puts "\n"
puts "Sorted\n"
word_counts_sorted.each do
        |word,count|
        puts word + " " + count.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1.9.1

```
>> words = {'the' => 6,'we' => 7, 'those' => 5, 'have' => 3}
=> {"the"=>6, "we"=>7, "those"=>5, "have"=>3}              
>> words.sort_by{ |x| x.last }.reverse
=> [["we", 7], ["the", 6], ["those", 5], ["have", 3]]
```

Comment: Again, I don't think this is sorting alphabetically on the hash key for equal value numbers.

Comment: yes, this does not sort the 2nd criteria, which i had missed.