# Wanting to sort a hash in ruby by value first, and key second

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting a hash in Ruby by its value first then its key.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790796/sorting-a-hash-in-ruby-by-its-value-first-then-its-key)

I need to order a hash so that the value is the first priority, and then when the values are the same it orders by the key.

I am currently sorting using this code, but I don't see how to do sort_by with a second element.

```
Hash[@card_value_counts.sort_by{|k, v| k * -1}]
```

Examples of what I'm looking for would be:

```
pre_sorted = {10=>1, 9=>2, 3=>2, 2=>1, 1=>1}
sorted = {9=>2, 3=>2, 10=>1, 2=>1, 1=>1}

pre_sorted = {12=>2, 10=>3, 9=>4, 5=>3}
sorted = {9=>4, 10=>3, 5=>3, 12=>2}
```

Comment: Not familiar with Ruby's `sort_by` function, but you could first sort by the key, then use a stable sort on the value.  (Same idea as radix sort.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Array has a cool feature: comparing two arrays with the `<=>` method will compare them element-by-element. You can exploit this for multi-value sorting:

```
sorted_hash = Hash[original_hash.sort_by { |k,v| [-1 * v, -1 * k] }]
```

UPDATE: Maybe you know this already, but I assumed you're using Ruby 1.9. In earlier versions, Hashes are not guaranteed to maintain their order.